# The Python "FOR" Loop Gives String Indices Error

Tags: python

Why doesn't the for loop make i an integer and loop it through each indice in my string?
This is just general expirementation with for loops.  Python makes it so minimal, I can barely get my head around how powerful the words "for" and "in" are now.

```
    >>> a = "1234567890"
    >>> print a[0]
    1
    >>> for i in a:
    ...     print a[i]
    ... 
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
    TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str
    >>>
```

Comment: You don't need the index in the case. Just do `for each in a: print each` to print each element of the string in turn...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your loop, `i` is each individual character in `a`.

To tackle your problem either way, consider either introducing `range`s or printing `i` directly.

```
for i in a:
    print i
```

or

```
for i in range(len(a)):
    print a[i]
```

Although the first solution is preferred (faster), they produce the same result.

```
In [1]: a = "abcdefghi"

In [2]: for i in a:
...:     print i
...:     
a
b
c
d
e
f
g
h
i

In [3]: for i in range(len(a)):
    print a[i]
...:     
a
b
c
d
e
f
g
h
i
```

You can also further optimize the second solution by adopting `xrange`.

Answer (score 2):

In python when you do `for i in a`, i is the item in the list/string `a` as it goes sequentially through.

What you want to do is:

```
for i in a:
    print i
```

if you want to do it based on indexes you can do it using `range`

```
for i in range(len(a)):
    print a[i]
```

`range(len(a))` creates a list from 0 to the length of the list/string `a`

Answer (score 0):

It's because `s` is not an index

```
>>> a = "1234567890"
>>> print a[0]
1
>>> for s in a:
...     print s
... 
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
0
>>>
```